# Convert range index to coordinates in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to convert this kind of indexing:

```py
a = tf.ones((500, 1000))
a[1:150, 50:700]
```

Into :

```py
a[idx_x, idx_y]
```

We can obviously use a `while` loop to construct the two vectors. But what is the most efficient way to do this in **tensorflow**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the index values as:

```py
idx_x, idx_y = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(1, 150), tf.range(50, 700), indexing='ij')
```

Then you would use those as:

```py
b = tf.gather_nd(a, tf.stack([idx_x, idx_y], axis=-1))
```